# Sort 2-dimensional String array on Android

Tags: android

I want to sort a 2-dimensional String array like this

```
"xx", "text 1"
"aa", "text 2"
"mm", "text 3"
```

to look like this

```
"aa", "text 2"
"mm", "text 3"
"xx", "text 1"
```

I have already found a [method to do this in Java](http://techthinking.net/2010/02/sorting-two-dimensional-string-array-using-java/), but this won't work on Android (at least not with 1.6, which is necessary for me), because `columnComparator` is not available.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: coloumComparator is a class that was within the code. Its not within the java library. Just use the class that is there in that code and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColumnComparator is that guy's own class that he's created by extending Comparator. Do the same and it will work for you !

Comment: Arrrgghh, I really should have read read the whole code. Thanks and sorry for bothering.